# Determine the Matrix of a Composition Linear Transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am having some trouble trying to solve linear algebra exercices related to composition linear transformation. This seems to be a very important exercice for my professor since every test has one of this exercice. I learn better by studying solved examples, so if someone can help me solve this exercice it would be very important for me to be able to solve other exercices of this kind. It is the next:

> Consider the next linear transformations:
>
> g: IR3->IR2  and   h: IR^2->IR^4
>
> so that
>
> $$ M(g; Bc, B3) = \begin{bmatrix} 2&3&-1\\ 4&7&0\\\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> $$ M(h; B3, B4) = \begin{bmatrix} 2&4\\3&7\\-1&0\\0&3\\\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> where B3 and B4 are the basis:
>
> B3 = {(2,2), (0,2)}
>
> B4 = {(3,0,0,0), (0,0,0,3), (0,3,0,0), (0,0,3,0)}
>
> The question: Determine the matrix M(h ° g; Bc; B4).

I know that maybe I'm asking for too much, but it is really going to help me and probably other people too... Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that by "$Bc$" you refer to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, if that is the case, I will change the notation of the problem a little bit.

Let $\alpha=\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Let

$$\beta=\{(2,2),(0,2)\}$$
$$\gamma=\{(3,0,0,0), (0,0,0,3), (0,3,0,0), (0,0,3,0)\}$$

be basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^4$, respectively. If $g: \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $h: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^4$ are linear transformations so that:
the matrix associated with $g$ with respect to the bases $\alpha$ and $\beta$ is

$$[g]_{\alpha}^{\beta}= \begin{pmatrix} 2&3&-1\\ 4&7&0\\\end{pmatrix}$$

and the matrix associated with $h$ with respect to the bases $\beta$ and $\gamma$ is

$$[h]_{\beta}^{\gamma}=\begin{pmatrix} 2&4\\3&7\\-1&0\\0&3\\\end{pmatrix}$$

Then, the matrix associated with $h\circ g:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^4$ with respect to the bases $\alpha$ and $\gamma$ is simply
$$[h\circ g]_{\alpha}^{\gamma}=[h]_{\beta}^{\gamma}[g]_{\alpha}^{\beta}=\begin{pmatrix} 2&4\\3&7\\-1&0\\0&3\\\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 2&3&-1\\ 4&7&0\\\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 20&34&-2 \\ 34&58&-3 \\ -2&-3&1 \\ 12&21&0 \end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer :)